# Javascript split once at first occurrence of a number

Tags: javascript

I have a variable that I need to split once at first occurrence of a number resulting in alpha and numeric components.

case #1

```
var str = "S44.5";
I need the output to be "S" and "44.5"
```

case #2

```
var str = "44.5";
I need the output to be "" and "44.5"
```

How can I do this with Javascript? Please help!

Jane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use regular expression

**[Regular Expression DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fE6bI4/2)**

```
var text= "hello12";
var text= "s4.44";
var  text= "4.53";
var text= "aaa4.53";

var matches = text.match(/([a-zA-Z]*)([0-9\.]+)/);
```

Comment: Tip: `[0-9\.]`  ` \ ` is not necessary

Answer (score 2):

This split a letter before the number, and it also includes an empty string if this does not occur.

[image]

```js
var a = /([a-z]*)([\w.]+)/i.exec("S44.5");
var b = /([a-z]*)([\w.]+)/i.exec("44.5");

console.log("I need the output to be %s and %s", JSON.stringify(a[1]), JSON.stringify(a[2]))
console.log("I need the output to be %s and %s", JSON.stringify(b[1]), JSON.stringify(b[2]))
```